# Create textpattern with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create a pattern with text that repeats and is offset every row.

I already did that using an svg, but the problem is that I have to manually set the offset for every row, the text is a duplicate for SEO and it's overall a lot of work to swap the text.

Is there a way to do this with other "cleaner" methods? Like for example with Javascript create every word just once and duplicate it automatically with a set offset?
Or some library I can use to make this simpler and SEO friendlier?

For me it's important that they are all kind of treated on it's own, so you can hover one element and only this one element changes it's color, not every element with the same content (like in my example).

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: red;
}

a {
  fill: red; 
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">


  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" height="200" width="200">
    <text x="-100" y="5">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="20">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="35">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="50">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="65">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="80">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="95">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="110">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="125">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="140">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="155">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="170">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="185">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="200">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="215">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="230">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="245">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="260">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="275">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="290">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="305">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="320">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="335">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="350">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="365">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="380">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="395">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 3</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 4</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="410">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 5</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 6</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-120" y="425">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 7</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 8</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-140" y="440">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 9</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 10</a></tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="-100" y="455">
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 1</a></tspan>
        <tspan dx="15"><a href="#">Item 2</a></tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You can definitely use a JS loop to create that pattern.  However if SEO is an issue, the only way I see to avoid duplicate content is to use a canvas and mousemove/mousedown handling.

Comment: Thank you. I mean, yeah SEO is important. But my first goal would be to make this simpler with less manual work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to create all the "Item xx" elements in a loop, and leave it to CSS to control the flow of these elements:

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
for (let i = 0; i < 31*6; i++) {
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = "Item " + i;
    wrapper.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper > span {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: red;
  width: 90px;
  height: 20px;
}

/* Force a "line break" after every 6th element */
.wrapper > span:nth-child(6n+1) {
  clear: both;
}

/* Give the first of every three lines a shift of 60px */
.wrapper > span:nth-child(18n-17) {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

/* Give the second of every three lines a shift of 30px */
.wrapper > span:nth-child(18n-11) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.wrapper > span:hover {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Thats great! But I have some items multiple times. In total only 10 different and they have to be placed multiple times each equally around my screen. And they are not numbered. They have individual names (I just used the numbers for demo). Will this also work like that?

Comment: Sure, just feed the loop with an array of the texts you want. I also just numbered the items for the demo ;-)